# Get top n rows of every table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a database with ~180 tables and I'd like to get the top 10 records from all of them. Is there a way to do this in one query or do I need to write them all individually?

I migrated this database from AWS and need to have some idea of what types of values are in each table.

Ideally this would end up in a .csv or some type of a report.

Comment: You can't do it in one query because every table has different structure. You could do it with a function or in a `DO` sentence, but it depends on how you want to interact with the data. If it is just like a report or if you want to save it somewhere, if you want to generate everything dynamically. Anyhow, you have to be more explicit in your question, it's to broad. try readding this **[How to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**

Comment: Referring to the types, do you want to know the column type? like, if it is integer or varchar? or the kind of data it holds? You can check the datatypes easly in one query.

Comment: Sorry that was unclear - I just want to see, in each column, if it looks like there's a bunch of null values, and if there are values, what do they look like. The fields are all heavily abbreviated so it's not entirely clear what a field represents when just seeing the field name. Looking at a few values from it will hopefully make it clearer.

Comment: Interesting question. You want a sample of data. But how representative do you want it? Just 10 random rows for each table? Maybe the PostgreSQL histogram is what you need. It tells you stats on how disperse and how the values for each column are organized. If you go that route make sure you update the histogram first for each table using `analyze verbose my_table`.

Comment: What OS you are using?

Comment: @Abelisto Windows 7 and pgAdmin 4v3. I have access to Mac and Linux as well though.

Answer (score 1):

Using `bash`:

```
#!/bin/bash

SQL_TBL_LIST="select format('%I.%I', relnamespace::regnamespace, relname)
  from pg_class
  where relkind = 'r' and relnamespace not in ('pg_catalog'::regnamespace, 'information_schema'::regnamespace)"

PSQL_CALL="psql -X -c"

for table_name in $($PSQL_CALL "\copy ($SQL_TBL_LIST) to stdout"); do
    $PSQL_CALL "\d+ $table_name"
    $PSQL_CALL "select * from $table_name limit 10"
done
```

It provides something like

```
                                     Table "public.t"
 Column |  Type   | Collation | Nullable | Default | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
--------+---------+-----------+----------+---------+----------+--------------+-------------
 x      | integer |           |          |         | plain    |              | 
 y      | text    |           |          |         | extended |              | 

 x | y 
---+---
 1 | a
(1 row)

                                                           Table "public.foo"
   Column   |           Type           | Collation | Nullable |             Default              | Storage | Stats target | Description 
------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+----------------------------------+---------+--------------+-------------
 i          | integer                  |           | not null | generated by default as identity | plain   |              | 
 data       | numeric                  |           |          |                                  | main    |              | 
 created_at | timestamp with time zone |           |          |                                  | plain   |              | 
Indexes:
    "foo_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (i)

 i  |        data        |          created_at           
----+--------------------+-------------------------------
  1 |  0.749826541636139 | 2018-09-01 02:26:07.183046+03
  2 |   0.85738476132974 | 2018-09-01 02:26:07.183046+03
  3 |  0.814507594332099 | 2018-09-01 02:26:07.183046+03
  4 |  0.707018708344549 | 2018-09-01 02:26:07.183046+03
  5 |  0.523847402073443 | 2018-09-01 02:26:07.183046+03
  6 | 0.0278508486226201 | 2018-09-01 02:26:07.183046+03
  7 |  0.111673643812537 | 2018-09-01 02:26:07.183046+03
  8 | 0.0430165408179164 | 2018-09-01 02:26:07.183046+03
  9 |  0.358260124456137 | 2018-09-01 02:26:07.183046+03
 10 |  0.915565127041191 | 2018-09-01 02:26:07.183046+03
(10 rows)
```